# C# button that would add text from one textbox into another textbox based on a SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, forms

I am new to C# and need to create a little form application, that has two textboxes one that asks for a [File_ID] then when button is pressed send that number to a query and in another textbox display the output.

I have been playing around with it  a bit, and have something like this. But it is not working. I am not sure if I should go on a different direction. I would REALLY appreciate your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String str,dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USHOU2016\\USFi;Initial Catalog=HOU_2016_Project;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            str = "SELECT TOP 1,[Sender Name],[Subject]  from [OLE DB Destination] WHERE [CHAT #] ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";

           cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
           // dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           con.Close();

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query syntax is wrong it should rather be below. You have a extra `,` after `TOP 1` .. remove that

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Sender Name],[Subject]  from [OLE DB Destination] WHERE...
```

Again in your button click you are just creating the command `cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);` but never executing it. and just closing the connection.

In `textBox2_TextChanged` event handler you are trying to execute the query but connection has already gone. I think it's time you should consider reading about ADO.NET

Comment: Thank you. I will I just needed C# as a tool to ouput my SQL data in a form format. How would I execute the cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con); do I need to add anything to textbox 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  A couple of things to note:

1. since the button is executing your sql and populating the 2nd textbox, there's no need for the textbox_changed event
2. Using string concatenation to append your variables to your sql query is bad practice and makes your code susceptible to Sql Injection.  Instead, parameterize your sql inputs as shown in the code below.

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string query = "SELECT TOP 1,[Sender Name],[Subject] "
                       + " from[OLE DB Destination] WHERE[CHAT #] = :chatId ";
       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USHOU2016\\USFi;Initial Catalog=HOU_2016_Project;Integrated Security=True"))
       {
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("chatId", textBox1.Text); //use Sql parameters to protect yourself against Sql Injection!
           con.Open();

           SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           if (reader.HasRows)
           {
               reader.Read();
               textBox2.Text = reader[0] + " " + reader[1]; //or however you want your output formatted 
           }

            reader.close();
       }
   }
   }
   ```